# Filtering based on .count() of a forgein key field in Django querysets

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset, django-orm

So I have some Django 1.3 models like this:

```
class Type(models.Model):
  is_bulk = models.BooleanField()

class Component(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Type)
```

Some `Type`'s have 0 `Component`'s, some have 1, or 2, etc. How do I write a QuerySet that filters all Type's that have > 0 Components. i.e. exclude Types that have 0 Components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Type.objects.annotate(component_count=Count('component')).exclude(component_count=0)
```