# Django QuerySet with exclude & annotate not returning any results

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Based off [this SO question about counting forgein keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068771/filtering-based-on-count-of-a-forgein-key-field-in-django-querysets), I have a problem. This is my models:

```
class Type(models.Model):
  is_bulk = models.BooleanField()

class Component(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForgeinKey(Type, related_name="components")
```

I want to write a queryset that has all types, except those that have is_bulk=True and have no components. If is_bulk=False, it should be included. If is_bulk=True and you have 1+ linked Components, then you're included. If not, you're excluded.

Based off the answer, I tried this queryset:

```
Type.objects.annotate(num_components=Count('components')).exclude(is_bulk=True, num_components=0)
```

But it returns no results.

However this implies that there should be results:

```
>>> [(x.is_bulk, x.num_components) for x in Type.objects.annotate(num_components=Count('components'))]
[(False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0)]
```

All the Type objects have is_bulk=False and all of them have 0 Components. From reading [the .exclude(…) documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude), it should be `NOT(is_bulk=True AND num_components=0)`, which should be True for every Type. Right? (Have I made a misunderstanding here, if so, what's the correct queryset)

If not, why is this queryset returning `[]`, when it should return all of them? Is this a bug in Django 1.3?

Comment: You might want to print your Queryset's query attribute so you can read the SQL Django outputs.

Comment: You can try the exclude with one parameter at a time to see if the problem is `is_bulk=True`, `num_components=0` or using them together.

Comment: There is a typo in your models.py `parent = models.ForgeinKey(Type)` it should be ForeignKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by changing the queryset to:

```
types_qs.annotate(num_components=Count('components')).filter(Q(is_bulk=False) | (Q(is_bulk=True) & Q(num_components__gt=0)))
```

That works, but I can't see why my original one didn't. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this example and what you need I think is declaring a `related_name` in your field:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForgeinKey(Type, related_name='components')
```

That should do it

**UPDATE**

Based on your example:

```
>>> [(x.is_bulk, x.num_components) for x in Type.objects.annotate(num_components=Count('components'))]
[(False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0), (False, 0)]
```

And mine:

```
>>> [(x.is_bulk, x.num_components) for x in Type.objects.annotate(num_components=Count('components'))]
[(False, 3), (False, 0), (False, 1), (False, 4), (True, 2), (True, 3), (True, 1), (True, 1), (False, 2), (True, 7), (True, 0), (False, 0)]
```

I'm assuming you don't have objects with the requirements of your queryset:

```
Type.objects.annotate(num_components=Count('components')).exclude(is_bulk=True, num_components=0)
```

Your results:

```
[]
```

This are the results in my case:

```
[<Type: Type object>, <Type: Type object>, <Type: Type object>, <Type: Type object>]
```

Comment: I have done that in my model already and the problem occurs. I have updated the question